# Country code for Philippines

Tags: java, android, localization

I am trying to localize my app for Philippines. Could someone tell me what is the folder name to be used for values-xxx to use the Filipino language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISO 3166-2:PH is the entry for the Philippines...values-ph, or values-tl_PH for Tagalog language

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder name with Values-tl [image]